# Keeping two div the same length

Tags: css

I have two divs, main and side that I want to ensure stay the length of whichever is longer.

At the moment, the main is longer than the side, how can I make them stay the same height, depending on the content?

```
#main{
width:818px;
padding:20px;
float:left;
background-color:white;
border-top-left-radius:20px;
border-left:1px solid #909090;
border-top:1px solid #909090;
}

#side{
float:left;
width:230px;
padding:20px;
background-color:#FEF5CA;
border-top:1px solid #909090;
border-right:1px solid #909090;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching for "equal height columns"?

Answer (score 1):

```
display: table-cell;
```

CSS3 is your friend ;-)

Comment: @filipko Not necessary to set `display: table` on the parent element.  The browser will create internal elements as needed to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the display: table-cell you will need to delete the float attributes from your main and side. Then add display: table-cell to both and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What way would be best in replacing the table-layout to divs ??

Reformat everything like a table with the display property. ;)

HTML

```
<div class="table-div" style="width:100%">
    <div class="tr-div">
        <div class="td-div">td-div 1a</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 2a</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-div">
        <div class="td-div">td-div 1b</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 2b</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-div{display:table}
.tr-div{display:table-row}
.td-div{display:table-cell;border:1px solid silver}
```

jsFiddled here http://jsfiddle.net/sPm9M/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to each put them in classes. This will ensure all of your properties are the same. You could also do this:

CSS

```
    #main,#side {
    width: //the width
    }

    #main {
    width:818px;
padding:20px;
float:left;
background-color:white;
border-top-left-radius:20px;
border-left:1px solid #909090;
border-top:1px solid #909090;
    }

    #side {
    float:left;
width:230px;
padding:20px;
background-color:#FEF5CA;
border-top:1px solid #909090;
border-right:1px solid #909090;
    }
```