# Use CSS to create columns with equal heights

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have 2 columns and those columns need to have the same height.
Also, link with class link-arrow need to be 10px at the bottom of the column.
You can see my problem at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDkcX/3/).

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img src="http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/3977/84462809.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="right-item">
        <h2>Our Operations</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="link-arrow">
            View our operations
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    width: 315px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
.image-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 112px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; 
    background: blue;
}
.right-item {
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
    width: 186px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}
.link-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
```

Is it possible with css?

Thanks!

Comment: You will require a javascript plugin to make that happen.

Comment: If the right item gets tall enough, I assume you want the blue background to emerge from the bottom of the left hand image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i know only 1 html element that can adapt to equal height with others :: a `<td>` like in `display: table-cell;`

Go try this answer : [Keeping two div the same length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407413/keeping-two-div-the-same-length/16429487#16429487)

Reformat everything like a table with the display property. ;)

HTML

```
<div class="table-div" style="width:100%">
    <div class="tr-div">
        <div class="td-div">td-div 1a</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 2a</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-div">
        <div class="td-div">td-div 1b</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 2b</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-div{display:table}
.tr-div{display:table-row}
.td-div{display:table-cell;border:1px solid silver}
```

No javascript required.

jsFiddled here http://jsfiddle.net/sPm9M/

Comment: If you were to try this, you might have a lot of trouble placing the bottom link in its proper place.

Comment: It's only a problem in Firefox.

Comment: Salut Marc, hi cimmanon. Thanks for the tips. I am testing with positions. http://jsfiddle.net/sPm9M/3/

Comment: If your going to use all those divs why not just use a table? No reason to use an advanced css property

Comment: @ProfileTwist Were you addressing this comment to the OP ?

Comment: @MilchePatern If you are going to use all those divs why not just use a table?

Comment: @ProfileTwist I am not to use nothing at all. But some how, `<table><tr><td>`  is much like (in markup structure) `<div><div><div>`, witch represents 3 markups. About using `<div>` or `<table>`, it's the OP choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure the left column will be bigger, you can use absolute positioning on the text like [this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jDkcX/4/)
Basically, `.block` is given a relative position and the right hand column is as follows:

```
.right-item {
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
    width: 186px;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    top:0; bottom:0; right:0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good way of doing this if the left image controls the overall height of the containing block.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution Using Table-Cells

If you are not sure if the left or right column will determine the overall height of the parent container, you can try using CSS tables as follows.

The HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img src="http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/3977/84462809.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="right-item">
        <h2>Our Operations</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="link-arrow">
        View our operations
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.block {
    width: auto; /* float causes shrink-to-wrap, so just use auto */
    float: left;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
.image-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 112px;
    background: blue;
}
.image-wrap img {
    vertical-align: top; 
}
.spacer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf; 
    border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf; 
}
.right-item {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 186px;
    background: green;
    padding-bottom: 2.00em; /* allow some room for .link-arrow */
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.link-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 137px; /* 112+15+10 need some math here... */
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

To get some finer control over the spacing, add a third column `div.spacer` to separate the left and right columns if needed.  You can add borders to it too and so on.

The `.link-arrow` needs some special attention.  Absolute positioning does now work within table cells, but you can use it with respect to the containing block (`.block`).  However, you need to determine the `left` offset manually and also allow some bottom padding on `.right-item` so prevent any text crowding or overlap.

See demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/sFY7v/

Comment: A bit more fiddly than my answer, but will work even if you're not sure which column will dictate the size, +1.

Comment: I agree, not knowing which column is taller adds a lot of complications!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Pre-requisites: You will require jquery to be loaded to make this plugin work.

Refer to the link below to achieve the results:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/#.Ubcl4-vGX79

Comment: Thanks but I know for that plugin. I just want to do that only with css, but I didn't find solution.

Comment: The CSS is loaded before the DOM is loaded. So using the static CSS only it wont be possible to do so as the data will be created after the css is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a height on the .right-item element.

```
.right-item {
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
    width: 186px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
}
```